# Cantidad de registros ingresados el dia de hoy en php

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy realizando un contador que me avise cuantos registros se han realizado en el día y así poder saber cuantas personas falta que ingresen su información. El problema es que me entrega 0, no me esta contando la cantidad de registros.

la fecha esta en el mismo formato como aparece en las tablas, intente con un while y tampoco me funciono

```
  $date = date("Y-m-d");
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Patente) AS total FROM Solicitud WHERE Fecha_Reg=$date";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
  $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
echo 'Cantidad de Solicitud de Combustible que se han ingresado hoy: ' . $fila['total'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que encerrar entre comillas simples a tu variable `$date`, quedando así:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Patente) AS total FROM Solicitud WHERE Fecha_Reg='$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
echo 'Cantidad de Solicitud de Combustible que se han ingresado hoy: ' . $fila['total'];
```

Comment: gracias, a veces uno no ve esos detalles tan pequeños, estaré mas atenta xD